# If you cast Emergency Force Sphere while flying, is it a sphere or a hemisphere?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, flight

My wizard is flying 50' in the air via [Overland Flight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/o/overland-flight/). He casts [Emergency Force Sphere](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/emergency-force-sphere/).

Is he surrounded by a full sphere or only a hemisphere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spell [*emergency force sphere*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/emergency-force-sphere/) has the entry ***Effect*** 5-ft.-radius hemisphere of force centered on you, and the spell's description, in part, says that "you create a hemispherical dome of force…. The bottom edge of the dome forms a relatively watertight space if you are standing on a reasonably flat surface."

Thus, even if the caster is *not* "standing on a reasonably flat surface," the spell *still* creates a hemisphere that apparently *never* covers the caster from below. This should render caster that's also flying wholly vulnerable to effects launched from directly underneath the caster, while effects aimed at the caster from underneath but at an angle may see the caster receive some degree of [cover](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Cover).